# Postman not Working with Laravel Valet (Local)

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-valet

When I use Postman to send or get data to/from my local Laravel applications it always returns the error...

> Could not get any response.
>   For example, a GET request to
>   http://demo_app.localhost/api/data.

I use Laravel Valet on my Mac. It looks like Postman can't find the local domain.

Comment: Since you are using valet, do you need to request to https, not http?

Comment: I tried both with the same result

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when trying to use valet with Postman and what fixed it for me was turning off the SSL verification in Settings > General. I believe valet is using some internal SSL certificate by default that cannot be verified properly by Postman.

[image: SSL setting]

Answer (score 0):

Use TLD `.test`, if your Valet version is up-to-date and not specifically configured to use `.localhost`.

Should be like http://demo_app.test/api/data

See official docs for background:

[Valet documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet) at chapter "Using Another Domain".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and used all the suggestion above, none of them works.
For my case, I used the following command to fix the problem:

```
php artisan optimize
```

This clears the cache and config files and reloads the new api Routes added to the Laravel framework.